# Getting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

this is my code.

```
package com.example.lambda.dynamodbdemo;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.PutItemOutcome;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.spec.PutItemSpec;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class PuttingPersonHandler implements RequestHandler<Person, String> {
    private DynamoDB dynamoDb;
    private String TABLE_NAME = "People";
    private String REGION = "ap-northeast-2";

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Person input, Context context) {
        this.initDynamoDbClient();

        putData(input);
        return "Saved Successfully!!";
    }

    private void initDynamoDbClient() {
        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(REGION).build();
         this.dynamoDb = new DynamoDB(client);
    }

    private PutItemOutcome putData(Person person) 
              throws ConditionalCheckFailedException {
                return this.dynamoDb.getTable(TABLE_NAME)
                  .putItem(
                    new PutItemSpec().withItem(new Item()
                            .withPrimaryKey("id",person.id)
                            .withString("firstName", person.firstName)
                            .withString("lastName", person.lastName)));
            }
}

class Person {
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

when I trying to run function on AWS Lambda with this json massage,

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "firstName": "Min",
  "lastName": "Heo"
}
```

and I get this error

Input value must not be null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input value must not be null
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.InternalUtils.rejectNullValue(InternalUtils.java:595)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.InternalUtils.checkInvalidAttribute(InternalUtils.java:620)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item.withString(Item.java:108)
    at com.example.lambda.dynamodbdemo.PuttingPersonHandler.putData(PuttingPersonHandler.java:38)
    at com.example.lambda.dynamodbdemo.PuttingPersonHandler.handleRequest(PuttingPersonHandler.java:22)
    at com.example.lambda.dynamodbdemo.PuttingPersonHandler.handleRequest(PuttingPersonHandler.java:1)

Is there any way to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html: :

> The get and set methods are required in order for the POJOs to work with AWS Lambda's built in JSON serializer